# HAML indentation issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I'm pretty new to rails and haml.. and I can't get this to work right.

I have this partial (_head.html.haml):

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type', :content => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"}
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'main'
  %body
```

And then in my application.html.haml:

```
= render :partial => 'shared/head'
#wrapperDIV 
  = yield :layout
```

But the output is not exactly what I intend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <link href="/stylesheets/main.css?1266030236" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
<div id='wrapperDIV'></div>
```

Obviously `<html>` and `<body>` should wrap #wrapperDIV, but it seems like the partials are not getting put in the right hierarchy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partials are implicitly closed at the end.  They're supposed to be complete sub-objects.

Here's what you want:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{'http-equiv' => 'Content-Type', :content => "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"}
    = stylesheet_link_tag 'main'
  %body
    #wrapperDIV 
      = yield :layout
```

If you wanted to put your `meta` and `stylesheet` calls in a partial, you could do that, but all the tags you have open at the end of a haml document will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The `html` and `body` needs to be in `application.html.haml`

```
!!!
%html
  = render :partial => 'shared/head'
  %body
    #wrapperDIV 
      = yield :layout
```

Comment: I tried that, but then `html` still doesn't wrap `body`. There has to be a way for this to work though..

Comment: Everything that you want to wrap the content of the page needs to be in `application.html.haml`, including both `html` and `body`.